# AdMob ads not displaying (with Logcat output)

Tags: java, android, admob

i try to display admob ads in android, but i fail.
If i set the background from adView to black, it shows the color but not the ad

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="example.de.myapplication" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
</application>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="MY PUB ID">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

and my MainActivity:

```
package example.de.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice("MYID")
            .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Here is my formatted Logcat Output: http://pastebin.com/JdfrWLAZ

Answer (score 2):

I know this sounds stupid but have you made sure that your device was connected to the internet when you ran the app?

Edit:
Not sure if it will work but have you made sure that you have the Google API's and Google Repositories downloaded in your Android SDK via SDK Manager.

Comment: sure with wifi and mobile internet. I added my logcat with pastebin.

Comment: Not sure if it will work but have you made sure that you have the _Google API's_ and _Google Repositories_ downloaded in your **Android SDK** via **SDK Manager**.

Comment: Just Noticed your answer. Good Job

Answer (score 1):

Have you double checked your device id and that you're not just testing on another emulator or device with a different id?

Comment: yes of course. I tested on both, my device and an emulator.  I added my logcat with pastebin.

Comment: From posted log "Didn't find class "com.google.ads.AdView" please attach grade.  And from your layout I see you have ads:adUnitId="MY PUB ID". Is this your ad unit id or did you use your publisher id?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that I had AdAway installed.
After removing it, the AD is showing.

Answer (score 0):

You have padding left, right, top, bottom in your parent layout remove it and try again! I had the same problem with you and I just solve it with that trick